# Fast api migrate

Tags: database, fastapi

Currently I know the issue of flask and I want to migrate to fast api because the asynchronous issue is possible in the response of the api, but I have been looking and I have not found the equivalence of flask migrate in fast api, flask migrate is mainly responsible for catching the models already established in our app and if a column is added to the new model, only flask db migrate and flask db upgrade should be used and that what it does is update the ddl of the table that is in the database, but I cannot find the equivalence in fast api

This is the link to migrate with flask migrate
https://j2logo.com/tutorial-flask-leccion-11-update-data-base-sqlalchemy/

Comment: `flask-migrate` is a thin-ish layer on top of Alembic. Alembic can do everything for you as well - `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "message"` and `alembic upgrade head` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As @MathLindh mentioned, flask-migrate is just an abstraction of alembic migrations. you can do the same with FAST API by integrating alembic. you can refer to the below link for info.
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#migrations